# django crispy-forms & floppyforms w/ bootstrap: how to get help_text into a ModelForm?

Tags: django-forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-floppyforms

I'm having a small (but annoying) problem with django forms right now.

I'm using:

- twitter bootstrap
- django floppyforms (just for the html5 widgets)
- django crispy-forms (for the template tags & rendering)
- my forms are all **ModelForms** and that shouldn't change if possible

I've searched the whole web and tried a lot of stuff, but I can't figure out the place where I can inject help_text="Some random help text" into the code. So here's my code(abbreviated for sanity reasons):

```
#forms.py:

import floppyforms as forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import *
from crispy_forms.bootstrap import *
from courses.models import *

class CourseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Course
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput,  # This is a floppyforms widget
        ...
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = 'POST'
        self.helper.form_id = ''
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_action = ''  # redirect in the view
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True  # means that I want <span> elements 
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Fieldset('Create a new course',  # fieldset label
                Field('title', placeholder="Something...", css_class="span4"),
                ...
            ),
            FormActions(
                Submit(
                    'submit',
                    'Submit',
                    css_class="btn-primary"
                )
            ),
        )
        super(CourseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried to inject it as an 'attrs' dict into the widget and as an attr into the Field.

```
forms.TextInput(attrs={'help_text': 'Some help text'})
Field('title', help_text="Some help text", css_class="span4")
```

Needless to say that it didn't work. **I need a hook** to put the help text into a 'span' or 'p' inside my controls-div, not into the input widget.

My template is very minimal and it should stay that way if possible. I don't want to iterate over the form fields:

```
#create_course.html

{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content%}
{% crispy form %}
{% endblock content%}
```

That renders as the following html:

```
<div id="div_id_title" class="clearfix control-group">
  <label class="control-label requiredField" for="id_title">
    Title
    <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="id_title" class="span4 textinput textInput" type="text" placeholder="Something..." maxlength="60" required="" name="title">
  </div>
</div>
```

With the help text it should look like this:

```
<div id="div_id_title" class="clearfix control-group">
  <label class="control-label requiredField" for="id_title">
    Title
    <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
  </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="id_title" class="span4 textinput textInput" type="text" placeholder="Something..." maxlength="60" required="" name="title">
    **<span class="help-inline">Supporting help text</span>**
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated! I haven't tried to inject the code through views.py into the form, but I see no point in doing that. It should be possible to do that in forms.py with the right hook and syntax.

Sorry for the long text for such a simple problem ;)

Comment: Ok I found out what the problem was. Since I didn't really define the Fields anywhere (I only defined the field widgets), I couldn't access the help_text. You can either define the Fields in forms.py (which is unnecessary and bad practice, they're ModelFields. DRY!) or set the help_text for the model in models.py.

Comment: I'm glad you work it out. Better to specify help_text in models. But you can also override fields without redefining it, see slide 34 here https://speakerdeck.com/u/maraujop/p/advanced-django-forms-usage

Comment: Could you post your comment as answer and accept it? That way it doesn't show up as an unanswered question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. Since I didn't really define the Fields anywhere (I only defined the field widgets), I couldn't access the help_text. You can either define the Fields in forms.py (which is unnecessary and bad practice, they're ModelFields after all) or set the help_text for the model in models.py.

Hope that helps others who have a similar problem.

Comment: Just to add to that, if for some reason you did not want to use the help text set in the model, you can always access the created fields in the ModelForm's `__init__` method.